# UUIDFactory jar file

Tags: java, jar, uuid, hl7, hl7-v3

I am running the sample HL7 message parsing project available [here](https://cdac.in/index.aspx?id=hi_hs_medinfo_hl7_download).

When running any file I am getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/registry/ebxml/util/UUIDFactory
at cdac.medinfo.sdk.hl7282.utils.StandardMethods.generateUUID(StandardMethods.java:317)
at cdac.medinfo.sdk.hl7282.utils.HL7Config.enableLogging(HL7Config.java:114)
at in.cdac.hl7model.ADT_A01_FileTest.main(ADT_A01_FileTest.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.registry.ebxml.util.UUIDFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Which is the jar file for the `UUIDFactory` class? I have the following jars in my classpath:

[image: jar files in classpath]

Comment: I would imagine you are missing this. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.registry/jaxr-impl/1.0.8

Comment: Doesn't seem so, adding this jar still gives the same error.

Comment: How did you add the file to the classpath?

Comment: The jar is a different one, I got it from the SDK developers, that fixes the issue.https://www.dropbox.com/s/rxu4jwpqaec1uq7/uuid.jar?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

The jar file for this dependency is available here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rxu4jwpqaec1uq7/uuid.jar?dl=0